# mysql first free position id from category

Tags: mysql, position

I've been searching for a query to get the first free position id in some category id. So far i've seen query's with left join and stuff but nothing to find with WHERE clause. So, my problem is to find the first free position in an category where products are added.

Example:

```
id_category id_product position
100 10 0
100 11 1
100 12 3
100 13 4
100 14 5
100 15 7
100 16 8
100 17 9
```

So I'm looking for lucky number 2 where id_category = 100.

As far I had this..

```
SELECT MIN(cp.id_category + 1) AS position FROM ps_category_product cp

LEFT JOIN ps_category_product cp1 ON cp.id_category = cp1.id_category

WHERE cp1.position IS NULL
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
SELECT MIN(position), id_category
FROM ps_category_product o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ps_category_product i 
    WHERE i.position    = o.position + 1
      AND i.id_category = o.id_category
)
GROUP BY id_category;
```

Comment: Ok, and after the WHERE i.position = o.position + 1 I added AND i.id_category = 123. Than I get the lowest free position of that category. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, make sure that the categories match. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a possible position can be anywhere between the min position and max position in your table and you have a table somewhere in your db that has sequential id numbers (in the example below I have dates) then you can create a list of all positions a category could have then exclude those they do have. for example

```
drop table if exists o;
create table o
(id_category int, id_product int, position int);
insert into o values
(100 ,10 ,0),
(100 ,11 ,1),
(100 ,12 ,2),
(100 ,12 ,3),
(100 ,13 ,4),
(100 ,14 ,5),
(100 ,14 ,6),
(100 ,15 ,7),
(100 ,16 ,8),
(102 ,16 ,8),
(102 ,17 ,9);

select a.id_category, min(possible)
from
(
select o.*,p.possible
from
(
select 0 as possible
union
select id from dates d
where d.id <= (select max(position) from o) + 1
) p
cross join (select distinct id_category from o) o
) a
left join
(select * from o) b on b.id_category = a.id_category and b.position = a.possible
where b.position is null
group by a.id_category;
```

Result

```
+-------------+---------------+
| id_category | min(possible) |
+-------------+---------------+
|         100 |             9 |
|         102 |             0 |
+-------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```